# LWC - Send parameters from the record page to Apex class

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to get records from another object using the field values from the record page.
Here I have the Account object for which I am getting the recordId using the
`@api recordId` declaration. I want to send the value of the `segment_Id` field which is also in the account object. How do I pass along the value of the segment_id field with `@wire` declaration to retrieve data from a different object.

In the below code I have hardcoded the Id value to test if it is pulling any data, which it does. I want to pass the `Account.Segment_id` value there inside of hardcoding

Here is the full code I have so far -

```
import { LightningElement, api,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import SEGMENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Segment_ID__c';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import loadPersonalizedOffers from "@salesforce/apex/PersonalizedOffersController.loadPersonalizedOffers";

export default class Personalized_offers extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    fields=['Name','Segment_ID__c'];


    @wire(loadPersonalizedOffers, {Id: 'a2n17000000EhO7AAK'}) personalizedOffers({
        error, data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT after the below trials-**

I have tried all the below answers, still not reaching anywhere, now I am getting this error on record page load. As of now what I am trying is to get the segmentId track variable to be populated with the actual field value so that I can pass it to my next apex call.

[image]

Here is the new code -

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import SEGMENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Segment_ID__c';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import loadPersonalizedOffers from "@salesforce/apex/PersonalizedOffersController.loadPersonalizedOffers";

const SEGMENT_ID_FIELD = [SEGMENT_FIELD];

export default class Personalized_offers extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @track segmentId;
    
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        SEGMENT_ID_FIELD
      }) segmentId( data, error ) {
          if(data) {
            this.segmentId = getFieldValue(this.data, SEGMENT_ID_FIELD);
            console.log(this.segmentId);
          };
      };
}
```

****EDIT - 2**-- Not having any luck so far. Here is the code so far, after the mentioned changes**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import SEGMENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Segment_ID__c';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import loadPersonalizedOffers from "@salesforce/apex/PersonalizedOffersController.loadPersonalizedOffers";

const SEGMENT_ID_FIELD = [SEGMENT_FIELD];

export default class Personalized_offers extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @track segmentId;
    
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        SEGMENT_ID_FIELD
      }) segmentId( data, error ) {
          if(data) {
            this.segmentId = getFieldValue(this.data, SEGMENT_FIELD);
            console.log(this.segmentId);
          };
      };
}
```

**EDIT 3 - After several trials I am getting the data console logged, a few questions on the data.**
In the log below I have the console log firing even when I have it specified inside `if(data)`. It is on the second log I see the actual data.

Questions

1. In the snip below I have the console log method firing twice even when I have it specified inside `if(data)`. How do I make fire once when we have the data available?
2. Why is it firing all the other values when I have just asked for the value of just one field which Segment_ID__c?
3. How can I extract the Segment_ID__c value from the output in the snip below?

[image]

Here is my final code -

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import SEGMENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Segment_ID__c';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import loadPersonalizedOffers from "@salesforce/apex/PersonalizedOffersController.loadPersonalizedOffers";

export default class Personalized_offers extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    @track segmentId;
    
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        fields: [SEGMENT_FIELD]
      }) segmentId( data, error ) {
          if(data != undefined) {
            this.segmentId = getFieldValue(data, 'Account.Segment_ID__c');
            console.log(this.segmentId);
          }
          else if(error) {
           
          }
      };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This we can do in three steps:

**Step 1** Get `Account` record data for that we need `recordId` which we have.

**Step 2** Now get `Segment_ID__c` field value from account record.

**Step 3** Finally get the `loadPersonalizedOffers` with the `Segment_ID__c` value.

Code will look something like this:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

/* ... */

import loadPersonalizedOffers from "@salesforce/apex/PersonalizedOffersController.loadPersonalizedOffers";

FIELDS = ['Segment_ID__c'];

export default class Personalized_offers extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track account;
    segmentId;
    
    /* ... */
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS }) /* Step 1 */
    getAccount({error, data}){
        if (error) {            
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading account',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                })
            );
        } else if (data) {
            this.account = data;
            this.segmentId = this.account.fields.Segment_ID__c.value; /* Step 2 */
            /* Now we can call the getPersonalizedOffers */
            loadPersonalizedOffers({Id: this.segmentId}).then((data)=> {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            }).catch((error)=> {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }
    }

    /* ... */

}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed steps, I get an error on the second @wire, it says  "Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration"

Comment: Added missing `track` decorator in the first import.

Comment: Give it a try now, it should work, didn't tried this so if there is still any error try to debug that.

Comment: I have updated my original post, with the edits. Still I was not able to get to an end to this. Please advise!

Comment: in the new code replace `this.segmentId = getFieldValue(this.data, SEGMENT_ID_FIELD)` with `this.segmentId = getFieldValue(this.data, SEGMENT_FIELD)`, `getFieldValue` takes 2nd parameter as a single field not a list of fields.

Comment: Tried the change, I get the same error on record load and the console.log says undefined

Comment: Can you update the new code in the post, as I don't see that?

Comment: I have added the latest code to the original post. Not lucky so far.

Comment: Were you able to notice anything wrong I did?

Comment: Yes, I found that, `getRecord` input should be `{recordId: '$recordId', fields: SEGMENT_ID_FIELD}` not just `{recordId: '$recordId', SEGMENT_ID_FIELD}` **fields** key name is missing.

Comment: Fixed **fields** property in the answer, all should work now.

Comment: I wish it worked, I copied your answer, commented all mine, still it doesn't work.

Comment: I finally got it working, I have updated my original post with a few questions, would you be having an answers for that? Thanks for the continued support

Comment: Thanks, I am closing this post, as the issue mentioned in this post has been solved

Answer (score 1):

Pass the accrount recordId to the [getFieldValue()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value) method, from lightning/uirecordapi, and get the segment_id. Pass this segment_id into the personalizedOffers wire adaptor.

Refer to the above link for an example of how the method works.

Comment: Thanks Naga, You guided me in the right direction, but my code still; needs some fixing.